# PIL, Image.fromarray make noises

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

[image]

i am doing conversion between images(alphabet I) and arr(np.array)
the mode is 'L', grayscale img.
there is no pixels like noise in np.array but when i did conversion.

`img = Image.fromarray(arr) 
img.save(path)`

then there are noises in saved img.
ex> arr[0] components are all 255 but there is some noise in the first line of saved image.

i don't know why noise happens in images.

Comment: Maybe caused by lossy compression. What format do you save in? To help us help you, please write example code conforming to [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to format of image.

Solution is to use non compressing format of image (such as .png or .gif)

Here is example which replicates this problem:

---

Sample files for this example are: 'demo.png' and 'demo.jpg' files which are equivalent in content.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
img_jpg = misc.imread('demo.jpg', mode='L')
img_png = misc.imread('demo.png', mode='L')
```

Here is output for variable img_jpg:

```
array([[ 17, 255,  82,   0,  74,  78,   0,  73],
   [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [134, 147, 146, 135, 131, 129, 131, 142],
   [255, 255,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [  3,  25, 255, 255, 129, 163,   0, 225],
   [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0,  32,  64,  92, 130, 167, 196, 219],
   [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Here is output for variable img_png:

```
array([[ 17, 255,  82,   0,  74,  78,   0,  73],
   [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [134, 147, 146, 135, 131, 129, 131, 142],
   [255, 255,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [  3,  25, 255, 255, 129, 163,   0, 225],
   [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0,  32,  64,  92, 130, 167, 196, 219],
   [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

Lets try saving them to file:

```
misc.imsave('img_jpg.jpg', img_jpg)
misc.imsave('img_png.png', img_png)
```

Now lets recover them:

```
img_jpg = misc.imread('img_jpg.jpg', mode='L')
img_png = misc.imread('img_png.png', mode='L')
```

Here is output for variable img_jpg:

```
array([[ 26, 251,  84,   0,  75,  88,   0,  67],
   [247, 253, 255, 250, 255, 235, 255, 255],
   [133, 166, 124, 132, 141, 121, 135, 143],
   [255, 235,  12, 255, 248, 255, 255, 250],
   [251, 255, 255, 252, 255, 240, 251, 243],
   [  4,  36, 222, 255, 137, 163,   0, 247],
   [  0, 251,  14,   5,   0,   6,   0,   0],
   [  3,  27,  65,  89, 122, 170, 204, 222],
   [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Here is output for variable img_png:

```
array([[ 17, 255,  82,   0,  74,  78,   0,  73],
   [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [134, 147, 146, 135, 131, 129, 131, 142],
   [255, 255,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [  3,  25, 255, 255, 129, 163,   0, 225],
   [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0,  32,  64,  92, 130, 167, 196, 219],
   [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

You can observe that .jpg file got corrupted while .png file had its original content unchanged.

Kind regards.